# Employment data by income at the state level

Tags: data-request, labor, income

Where can I find data on the number of people employed in each state for each level of income? I need data that includes at least the year 2014, and back to at least 2009.
I would like the following variables:
-income
-state of residence
-employment
-year

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is for 2014 (ACS 2014 1-year) from CensusReporter(.org)`*` by poverty status: http://censusreporter.org/data/table/?table=B17005&geo_ids=01000US,040|01000US&primary_geo_id=01000US

More information on this topic can be found from CensusReporter at http://censusreporter.org/topics/employment/

`*`The data ultimately comes from Census and you can use their FactFinder tool with this data table at http://factfinder.census.gov/bkmk/table/1.0/en/ACS/13_5YR/B17005/0400000US49

[image: screenshot from censusreporter.org]